# Coq: Simplify (negb (neqb true) to true using "rewrite" or "apply"?

Tags: functional-programming, coq, coq-tactic

In proofs, I want to simplify`(negb (negb true))` to `true` (likewise with `false`).

I know of Coq's `negb_involutive` procedure, but since my textbook hasn't introduced it, I think that I should somehow manage to imitate its functionality using only `rewrite` or `apply`.

Comment: Are you not allowed to use `simpl.`? Besides, `negb (negb true) = true` can be proved by `reflexivity.`, because the left-hand side and the right-hand side are definitionally equal.

Comment: Haven't used "simpl" before, but maybe I should look into that.

Comment: I think `simpl` should be enough for now. There is also a more powerful tactic `compute`, but it may create larger terms. You might want to look at this nice [cheatsheet](http://adam.chlipala.net/itp/tactic-reference.html).

Comment: @Shuzheng, I _really_ recommend that you check out the interactive course Software Foundations https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/current/index.html which gives a good introduction into using Coq.

Answer (score 4):

As Anton said, the typical procedure to solve this goal would be to use `reflexivity`, or its lower-level version `apply eq_refl`.

Recall that Coq is based on a programming language and in this case indeed the execution of `~~ (~~ true)` is easily seen to be `true` (where I abbreviate `~~ x = negb x`), in the same way it would return `true` in Python or C.

`apply eq_refl` will solve the goal as Coq will try to "compute" or "reduce" terms when tying to make things match. The type of `eq_refl` is `forall x, x = x`, thus when `~~ (~~ true)` is reduced to `true` your goal now becomes `true = true` and it can be solved. In this case, `simpl` will just reduce the goal for you to see it but it is technically not needed in the proof.

It is not idiomatic to apply `negb_involutive` in your case, this lemma is useful when the argument to `negb` is a variable, like in `~~ (~~ (~~ x)) = ~~ x`.

You'll find yourself using `rewrite` in most goals involving equality.